# Is it possible for non-military travelers to fly above the speed of sound?

Tags: air-travel

I know for example the Concorde flew faster than sound, but I believe the options are much more limited now. Is it possible to be in a plane that breaks the sound barrier, without having access to flights in planes like the F16?

Answer (score 7):

The only way that I know of (and I and @Stuart have both looked into this) is the MiG-29 flight.  You need some training, but then there are a few options to do this with one (as a passenger - don't worry, you don't need to know how to fly it).

There are some sites on the net describing the options, but for example, [flyajetfighter.com](http://www.flyajetfighter.com/fly-the-mig-29-jet-fighter-in-russia/) gives you several options, including:

> 3/ Stratospheric flight: reach the edge of space in the MiG-29. Fly up
> to 70,000 feet, twice as high as a normal airliner, and admire the
> curvature of the earth. The sky is pitch dark, and you are at **twice
> the speed of sound**. This is an extraordinary experience, and the only
> one so far to get you into the stratosphere.

Other than that, you *might* get 'lucky' in a regular passenger jet if something goes horribly wrong and you spiral into a spin and plummet towards the earth - but that's theoretical, and for obvious reasons, not something you want to experience.

**EDIT**

There are other options (just see [FlyAJetFighter.com](http://www.flyajetfighter.com/) and click the drop down list - but the MiG seems to be one of the more feasible options - there are several online companies showing this option with a brief google search.

Another example - the [MiG-21 is available in South Africa](http://www.incredible-adventures.com/mig21/#pricing) with a few companies, the example I've linked to has a full adventure deal for around US$10,000.

[Another site](http://www.atlasaerospace.net/eng/pilot-price.htm) - includes many options and a price list, ranging from US$3900 to US$22990, depending on the plane, but it's not clear which of those will be supersonic flights.

And it's worth noting that most of these companies (all of them if I'm not mistaken) won't take you if you have any medical conditions - ruling me out :(

Comment: Excellent answer again!! But could you maybe elaborate on what makes a flight on this plane more feasible than any other fighter plane? Also, prices would be nice :)

Comment: This is going on my bucket list! Thanks Mark :)
And there's plenty of other cool stuff to do down on the ground for you, as you seem to have figured out ;)

Comment: Just to be nitpicky, a 'spin' won't get you through the speed of sound. A spin is a low speed 'manouver'. You are probably looking for a 'spiral dive' if a brief period of high speed flight followed by a messy death are your goals.

Comment: "spiral into a spin then plummet" was I guess my way of saying "spiral dive" - guess I don't have the lingo down right :P Thanks!

Comment: @MarkMayo "you spiral into a spin and plummet towards the earth" - this is probably more of a physics question, however is it really possible to break the sound barrier under such circumstances?

Comment: Pfft, I have no idea. Was just a passing thought after considering the flight path of NASA's 'vomit comet' and wondering what its top speed is (incidentally still less than Mach 1.0).